# How to include class from addon after to be sure one class exists in the main plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, include

I have a plugin *Foo*. In this plugin, my main class can include several classes one of which is a useful abstract class named *Heading*.

**Foo.php** - my main class from my plugin **Foo**

```
namespace PluginFoo;

class Foo{ 

    public function __construct(){

        $this->include_dependencies();

    }

     private function include_dependencies(){
        ...
        if( file_exists( PLUGIN_DIR_PATH."admin/Heading" ) ) {
            include_once 'Heading.php';
        }
        ...
     }

}
new Foo();
```

I'm coding an addon *FooAddon*. In this addon, I need to include a class A which extends *Heading*. Something like this :

**FooAddon.php** - my main class from my addon **FooAddon**

```
namespace PluginFoo;

class FooAddon{ 

    public function __construct(){

        $this->include_dependencies();

    }

     private function include_dependencies(){
        ... 
        if( class_exists( "PluginFoo\\Admin\\Heading" ) ){
            if( file_exists( PLUGIN_ADDON_DIR_PATH."dir/MyClass.php" ) ) {
                   include_once 'dir/MyClass.php'; //<-- it's not included !
              }
        }
        ...
     }

}
new FooAddon();
```

**MyClass.php** - my class to include

```
namespace PluginFoo\Admin;

use PluginFoo\Admin\Heading; 

class MyClass extends Heading {
    ...
}
```

How can I include *Myclass.php* in this addon after to be sure *Heading.php* is included in my main plugin ?

Comment: if you are the developper of the main plugin, you can create an action "mainPluginIsLoaded". otherwise you can test the class existence with `if (class_exists("\\PluginFoo\\Admin\\Heading")) {`

Comment: I am the developer of the main plugin but I prefer the second solution. As you can see in my code, it' already inside it and that does not work. Maybe, I have no choice and I should use a custom action.

Comment: I don't understand why you use "file_exist". you code says "if the file MyClass.php doesn't exist, include it".

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I modify it but this is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I think just the class Heading does not exist at this moment. So, I would like to know how to include it after Heading class is included.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer which seems to be good.
I used the hooks *plugins_loaded* and *_admin_menu*.
The hook *_admin_menu* is before *admin_menu* so I can add an admin page menu.

**FooAddon.php**

```
namespace PluginFoo;

class FooAddon{ 

    public function __construct(){

        // Install needed components on plugin activation
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );

        // Include dependencies
        add_action('plugins_loaded',  array( $this , 'include_dependencies' ) );

        // Initialize the components
        add_action('_admin_menu',  array( $this , 'init' ) );

    }

    public function include_dependencies(){
        ... 
        if( class_exists( "PluginFoo\\Admin\\Heading" ) ){
            if( file_exists( PLUGIN_ADDON_DIR_PATH."dir/MyClass.php" ) ) {
                   include_once 'dir/MyClass.php';
              }
        }
        ...
     }

     public function init(){
        if( is_admin() ){
            if( ! class_exists( "PluginWPGroupSubs\\Admin\\MYCLASS" ) ) {
                error_log("MyClass was not included");
            }else{
                new MyClass();
            }
        }

    }

}
new FooAddon();
```