# How to init an addon correctly after the main plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing an addon which has a main plugin dependency.
I use POO so classes and namespaces to do this.

I would like to load an addon after the main plugin and does some check and init it correctly on the right moment.

I found an [awful solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288155/how-to-include-class-from-addon-after-to-be-sure-one-class-exists-in-the-main-pl) was to check if the main plugin is inactive thanks the function `is_plugin_inactive`. The problem of this solution was you need a hook wich load the addon later and create others problems - example : when you want to use the `wp_ajax_` hook.

```
 namespace MyPlugin;

 class AddonMainClass{

     public function __construct(){
         $this->init(); //<-- Option 1
         add_action('admin_init',  array( $this , 'init' ) ); //<-- Option 2
         add_action('_admin_menu',  array( $this , 'init' ) ); //<-- Option 3 
     }

     public function init(){
         if( is_admin() ){
            if ( is_plugin_inactive( 'main-plugin/MainPlugin.php' ) ) {
               // admin notices    
            }else{
               // Init the addon 
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Problems with each option**

- Option 1 : Impossible to use the function is_plugin_inactive() and I'm not sure the main plugin is loaded before.
- Option 2 : With this hook, my new menu item is not added when I call `add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'load_view_page'));` in a class inside my main Plugin to display all menu items.
- Option 3 : As I said before, the hook `_admin_menu` seems to be too late to init my plugin so it disturbs some hook loading like `wp_ajax_my_function`.

I tried to find a totorial to do this on the Web without success.

What is the best way to do this correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found to... :

1. Check if the main plugin is active just before to initialize the addon
2. init the addon before to add menu item or some hook adding like `wp_ajax_my_function`

> Use the hook `plugins_loaded` to init addons
>
> Use a function to check in pure PHP `classes`, `functions` and `constants` from the main plugin like [here](https://wpmayor.com/how-to-check-whether-a-plugin-is-active/)

```
 namespace MyPlugin;

 class AddonMainClass{

     public function __construct(){
         add_action('plugins_loaded',  array( $this , 'init' ) ); 
     }

     public function init(){
         if( is_admin() ){
              $is_main_plugin_active = $this->detect_plugin(
                array(
                      'classes' => array(   
                              'MyPlugin\\Common\\ClassA',
                              'MyPlugin\\Common\\ClassB'
                      ),
                      'functions' => array(
                              'MyPlugin\\useful_function'
                      ),
                      'constants' => array(
                              'MyPlugin\\PLUGIN_DOMAIN'
                      )
                )
            );
            if ( ! $is_main_plugin_active ) {
               // admin notices    
            }else{
               // Init the addon 
            }
         }
     }
     
     private function detect_plugin( $plugins ) {

         /** Check for classes */
         if ( isset( $plugins['classes'] ) ) {
             foreach ( $plugins['classes'] as $name ) {
                if ( class_exists( $name ) )
                    return true;
             }
        }

        /** Check for functions */
        if ( isset( $plugins['functions'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $plugins['functions'] as $name ) {
                if ( function_exists( $name ) )
                    return true;
            }
        }

        /** Check for constants */
        if ( isset( $plugins['constants'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $plugins['constants'] as $name ) {
                if ( defined( $name ) )
                    return true;
            }
        }

        /** No class, function or constant found to exist */
        return false;

    }

}
```